# componentDidMount called before real DOM is available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, render, getelementbyid

I'm very new to React. I need to get the height of an element, so I'm trying to get it at `componentDidMount` method. I understood that this method was called after rendering the component, which is at the end to write the real DOM I assume. However, `componentDidMount` is being called before the final DOM is available. How come?

```
componentDidMount() {
  const el = window.document.getElementById('comments'); // el is null
  console.log(el);  
}

resize() {
  const el = window.document.getElementById('comments'); // el is null
  console.log(el);
}

render() {
  const { name } = this.props;
  const Comments = this.props.comments.filter(comment => comment.body !== null && comment.body !== '').map(comment => <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />);
  return (
    <div ref={this.resize}>
      <div>
        <div id="comments">
          { Comments }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Add code example.

Comment: @RuiCosta done and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On React you shouldn't rely on DOM that is returned by render method. The component and the render part are 2 different processes in React so the approach from outside in doesn't work in React. What you can do is, save comments as a ref :

```
 componentDidMount() {
      var erd = elementResizeDetectorMaker();
      erd.listenTo(this.refs.comments, resize);
    }

    resize(element) {
       //do-some-thing
    }

    render() {
      const { name } = this.props;
      const Comments = this.props.comments.filter(comment => comment.body !== null && comment.body !== '').map(comment => <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />);
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div ref={comments => { this.comments = comments; }}>
              { Comments }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );

}
```

PS : In a similar situation I used this amazing library : https://github.com/wnr/element-resize-detector

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't have the real height of the element on that case

Comment: [String refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) are considered legacy and should be avoided in new code. Use functions like `ref={comments => { this.comments = comments; }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `const el = window.document.getElementById('comments');` (this is anti pattern)
is null because your select Node don't exist on `componentDidiMount` render lifecycle.

You need select your node's inner React pattern (or shadow DOM).

Change your code for this code block, replace javascript selector 'getElementBy' for refs of React. Check documentation  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
componentDidMount() {
  let el = this.refs['comments']
  console.log(el.clientHeight)
  this.resize()
}

resize() {
  let el = this.refs['comments']
  console.log(el.clientHeight)
}

render() {
  const { name } = this.props;
  const Comments = this.props.comments.filter(comment => comment.body !== null && comment.body !== '').map(comment => <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />);
  return (
    <div ref='comments'>
      <div>
        <div id="comments">
          { Comments }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```